# Turbo Frames not recognizing Javascript from the head

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, turbo

I'm working on building my template and have the initial steps down.  I'm on Rails 7.0.2.4, turbo-rails 1.1.1, Bootstrap 5.

In my layouts template's  I have the following:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application", data:{turbo:{track: "reload"}}, defer: true
```

Which links to my app/javascript/application.js, and the relevant parts here are:

```
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

The second part above enabled Bootstraps tooltips.

Back in my template, I break it down into three Turbo Frames:

```
%turbo-frame{id: "main_frame", data:{turbo:{action: "advance"}}}
    .container-fluid
        .row.flex-nowrap
            .col-auto.col-md-3.col-xl-2.px-sm-2.px-0.bg-dark
                %turbo-frame{id: "sidebar", data:{turbo:{action: "advance"}}}
            .col
                %turbo-frame{id: "content", data:{turbo:{action: "advance"}}}
                    = yield
```

First, there is the main_frame, which is then divided into a Sidebar and a Content frame.  Clicking on links in the sidebar, which have date-turbo-frame: "content" attributes, swaps out the Content frame with that necessary content.

Now, on most full Content frames, the top of that frame has a navigation header which has a button on the left and right sides and text in the middle:

```
%turbo-frame{id: "content", data:{turbo:{action: "advance"}}}
    .row
        .d-flex
            .p-2
                %a{href: path, data:{turbo:{frame: "content"}, 
                  bs:{toggle: "tooltip", placement: "bottom", 
                    title: "Back"}}, 
                  aria:{label: "Back"}}
                    %i.bi.bi-arrow-left-circle-fill{aria:{hidden: "true"}}
            .flex-grow-1
                // Some Text
            .p-2
                %a{href: new_path, data:{turbo:{frame: "new"}, 
                  bs:{toggle: "tooltip", placement: "bottom", 
                    title: "New"}}, 
                  aria:{label: "New"}}
                    %i.bi.bi-plus{aria:{hidden: "true"}}
```

When you navigate to this replaced Content, the tooltips do not work.  However, when you do a FULL page reload via the browser, the tooltips are suddenly working because the code is in the head.

Is there a way I can get the frames to load the necessary Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically with Turbo your JS is added into the head and not modified across pages loads.

So when you call :

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
```

Basically it will search the DOM for requested DOM nodes at the exact time your JS is appended to the application. And if your app refreshes a turbo Frame, then it won't be played. Please see this thread I replied recently : [How to load page specific custom Javascript functions in a Rails 7 app with Turbo, ImportMaps and Stimulus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359149/how-to-load-page-specific-custom-javascript-functions-in-a-rails-7-app-with-turb/73362166#73362166)

If you want your Tooltips being refreshed when new content is loaded then you have to use Stimulus, put the code into the `connect()` method of a Stimulus controller, and attach that controller to every part of your application that may contain tooltips.

You can also attach your controller to the `<html>` tag and add a mutation observer (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) inside the `connect()` method if you don't want to attach your Stimulus controller at many places across your app. (You can also add the Mutation Observer in `javascript/application.js` if you wish. Stimulus purpose is actually to prevent spamming Mutation Observers but if you have many Tooltips, it is still a viable solution)

Comment: Thanks!  This proved to be helpful.  For now I've wrapped the relevant turbo-frames with the data controller that has this code in it.  But it would be more efficient to put it in the html tab with a Mutation Observer later when I refactor (as I don't understand Mutation Observer enough yet to use it).