# Rails: How to refresh page and run the script automatically when I redirect to a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a html page with a script, It looks like

```
<html>
</html>

<script>
<script>
```

The page needs to run this script to display the content correctly.

But when I redirect to this page with following code:

```
redirect_to user_trips_path(params[:user_id])
```

I noticed that it will not refresh the page. If I refresh the page manually it will display the content correctly.

My question is how to make this automatic?

I try to google this question.

Comment: You probably have Turbo enabled. You may read this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359149/how-to-load-page-specific-custom-javascript-functions-in-a-rails-7-app-with-turb/73362166#73362166 Also inline JS through <script> is a bit out of scope and I don't have experience with it since Turbo/Stimulus. To me it should run on redirects but there are some edge cases https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/186

Comment: In addition to what @Maxence is saying that HTML is broken - you're missing a `</script>` end tag. If this is the actual code thats running it will create a syntax error when the JS intrepreter runs into `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

**There are unlimited ways to refresh a page** - but some helpful aspect of your situation:

1- html tag:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">

[w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)

put it on your html or inject it with JS after page load.

2- JavaScript or jQuery:

[How do I refresh a page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-do-i-refresh-a-page-using-javascript)

3- if you have View on your Rails app you can create a route and method for run sample_name.js.erb and then in this file with some JS code you can open your partial and main .html.erb file

--

If after the first time you want to run a script to start to refresh the page you can redirect users with special param in **user_trips_path** and then in your JS code check if its present then run your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 7

If you want to disable Turbo Drive you can set `Turbo.session.drive = false` in your javascript/application.js file.

```
   import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
   Turbo.session.drive = false
```

=> It will reload the page while navigating