# How do I get JS assets to work for Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some trouble working with JS in my Rails app - the only "solution" I've managed to produce is *copy-pasting the scripts into all my layouts*, which is a pain.

Now I've tried creating a new rails app, then making a function in `app/javascript/application.js` that just displays an alert. Trying to call this function in my browser's developer console gives me a reference error.

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.>
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

function fishy(msg) {alert(msg);}
```

from `app/views/layouts/application*`:

```
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
```

This goes for both development and production environments.

In my proper project, I've been using Chartkick do display graphs - that suddenly stopped working the other day, but only for the remote server and not in my local dev environment.
Unlike the test app, this one has a `app/assets/javascript` folder - containing a `application.js` file:

```
//= require chartkick
//= require Chart.bundle

function fishy(msg) {alert(msg);}
```

(That test function doesn't work either..)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In your application.js file from the first example of your new Rails app, you don't call your function.

After `function fishy(msg) {alert(msg);}` you should just add  `fishy("hello")` to see the alert.

Also I don't think you can call this function in your Ruby erb file within `<script></script>` as it is not available to the global scope by default.

If you want to make it available, then maybe attach it like this :

```
window.fishy = function fishy(msg) {alert(msg);}
```

and call it in your pages like :

```
<script>
  window.fishy("hello")
</script>
```

Also I am bundling with esbuild server-side so I am not too sure there is something wrong with your importmaps setup. (Also Importmaps or Jsbundling/Esbuild are really about importing external JS libraries from NPM)

Though adding JS inline in every of your pages is not something that is really done with Rails 7. You better use Turbo and Stimulus which are parts of Hotwired. I wrote a quick thread about it, maybe it could be of help : [How to load page specific custom Javascript functions in a Rails 7 app with Turbo, ImportMaps and Stimulus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359149/how-to-load-page-specific-custom-javascript-functions-in-a-rails-7-app-with-turb/73362166#73362166)

Comment: Attaching to `window` does not work, unfortunately. I get a type error saying it is not a function - dev console says `window.fishy` is undefined. Is there another way to make it available globally?

Comment: Are you sure your JS is properly added to your HTML pages ? I am not familiar with importmaps then I can't really help. While bundling with Esbuild and compressing with Sprockets, it is added the good old way : `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>`