Turbo: how to re-evaluate some js files after render?
I'm still pretty new to Hotwire. I have this issue, which I think is a common issue with Turbo. I remember I had it before with Turbo-Links, this is because I ended up deactivating it always on my projects.
The problem seems to be that the .js files are not re-evaluated after the Frame is loaded.
These JS have some after-render logic, like the Bootstrap "tooltips", which requires a query selector to go through all the elements that match and activate the functionality.
I have been searching in Google with no luck:

rails turbo reevaluate js
rails javascript_include_tag and turbo reload

How can I ask Turbo to reevaluate some of my js files imported with javascript_include_tag like in here?:
<%= javascript_include_tag "phoenix/vendors/dayjs/dayjs.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "phoenix/assets/js/phoenix.js" %>

I was expecting something like:
<%= javascript_include_tag "phoenix/assets/js/phoenix.js", turbo_reload: true %>


I answered a similar question some time ago : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359149/how-to-load-page-specific-custom-javascript-functions-in-a-rails-7-app-with-turb/73362166#73362166 But if you are not using Stimulus you may add some mutation observers in your JS Though Turbo works well with Stimulus

The reason you're not finding anything is that non-impotent and non-delegated event handlers are a known issue not just with Turbo but every javascript framework in existance that dynamically inserts contents into the DOM. They either end up not doing anything or attaching the same event handler over and over. My advice is to just select libraries that are not as shit.

You are probably looking for a turbo:frame-load listener.
Here's an example:
document.documentElement.addEventListener('turbo:frame-load', function (e) {
  // Initialize bootstrap tooltips and other logic here
});

Source:
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events
